# Redirecting domain.com to www.domain.com

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to redirect all requests to http://domain.com to http://www.domain.com, hence I use the following .htaccess placed in the root of my site:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

This works very nice, except in subfolders where I do some more URL rewriting:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /articles/
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php [L]
```

In fact nothing happens if I enter the URL: http://domain.com/articles/article.html
Expected behavior would be a redirect to http://www.domain.com/articles/article.html

What would be the best way to achieve the result?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [RewriteOptions](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteoptions) directive to tell Apache to use .htaccess from parent folder after finishing processing rules from local .htaccess:

```
RewriteOptions inherit
```

But parent rules will be process AFTER local .. which you may not like (as result URL may look like `http://www.domain.com/articles/index.php` which will be visible in address bar).

Ideally you want to move all into single .htaccess -- if you can.

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought this should work, if you have it in the sub folder:

```
RewriteBase /articles/
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^website\.com [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.website.com/articles/$1 [R=301,NC]
```